# Prove that $\operatorname{ran} f \subseteq \operatorname{dom} g \implies\operatorname{dom} (g \circ f)=\operatorname{dom} f$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Some preliminaries: A function $f$ is a binary relation such that $(x,y_1) \in f$ and $(x, y_2) \in f$ implies $y_1 = y_2$.

$\operatorname{ran} f = \{y: \exists x$ such that $(x,y) \in f\}$

$\operatorname{dom} f = \{x: \exists y$ such that $(x, y) \in f\}$

$g \circ f = \{(x,y): \exists z$ such that $(x,z) \in f$ and $(z, y) \in g\}$

Can someone verify my proof?

> Prove that $\operatorname{ran} f \subseteq \operatorname{dom} g \implies\operatorname{dom} (g \circ f)=\operatorname{dom} f$

Let $x \in \operatorname{dom} f$.

Then, $\exists y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$

Since $\operatorname{ran} f \subseteq \operatorname{dom} g$, we have $y \in \operatorname{dom} g$

But then, $\exists z$ such that $(y,z) \in g$

Since $(x,y) \in f$ and $y,z \in g$, $(x,z) \in g \circ f$

But then, $x \in \operatorname{dom} g \circ f$

So, $\operatorname{dom} f \subseteq \operatorname{dom} g \circ f$

Now, suppose $x \in \operatorname{dom} g \circ f$

Then, $\exists y$ such that $(x,y) \in g \circ f$.

So, $\exists z$ such that $(x, z) \in f$ and $(z,y) \in g$

But then, $x \in \operatorname{dom} f$, since $(x,z) \in f$

So, $\operatorname{dom} g \circ f \subseteq \operatorname{dom} f$

Therefore, $\operatorname{dom} f = \operatorname{dom} g \circ f$

Comment: I'd say this is correct.